# DIV as link only css modification

Tags: html, hyperlink, onclick

I try to make whole div a link only by changing CSS I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
.gw-go-col-wrap-0 {
  cursor:pointer;
  onclick:"onclick="location.href='/login?dis=yes'"
}
```

Can onclick be use in CSS? Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use onclick in CSS. Use it in your div instead or with JavaScript.

with HTML:

```
<div onclick="location.href='/login?dis=yes'"></div>
```

or with JavaScript:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName(".gw-go-col-wrap-0");
for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
  els[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
    location.href='/login?dis=yes'
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok thx but problem is that I can change only css i can't by any way add onclick or Java script directly to div

Comment: If you cannot edit even the HTML, then you can not turn it into a link.